# Find files created in a particular ssh session or date

Tags: unix, ssh

How can I find all the files that were created by a particular session using ssh?

Or search for files that were created/modified on a particular date?

Comment: This is a serverfault question, not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Maybe he's writing unix auditing software in bash.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the find command with the various switches of -mtime -ctime and -atime

Quoted from this link: http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/selecting_files_by_age.shtml

To find html files that have been modified in the last seven 24-hour periods (days), I can use -mtime with the argument -7 (include the hyphen):

```
find . -mtime -7 -name "*.html" -print
```

Answer (score 2):

You can list the open files on your system with `lsof -n`. To find files updated in the last 5 minutes `find . -cmin -5`.